# How to send a file to a REST service?

Tags: android, rest, file

I want to get file in rest service from android. In my code i send `filestream` from android via `url`. If i use like this My entire app is not working by saying...

**Logcat**

> Operation `Fileacces` in contract 'IREST' has a query variable named
>   `stream` of type `System.IO.FileStream`, but type
>   `System.IO.FileStream` is not convertible by `QueryStringConverter`.
>    Variables for UriTemplate query values must have types that can
>   be converted by `QueryStringConverter`

**Here I have post my coding FYR**

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == FILE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri content_describer = data.getData();

                String src = null;
                try {
                    src = getFilePath(UploadActivity.this, content_describer);
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("src is: ", src);
                source = new File(src);
                 fname = source.getName();

                Button text = (Button) findViewById(R.id.txt);
                text.setText(fname);


                text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        try {
                            FileOpen.openFile(UploadActivity.this, source);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });


            }
        }
```

**Onclick event in action bar icon:**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.mybutton) {
           new Save().execute();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**SAVE function asynctask**

```
private class Save extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                fis=new FileInputStream(source);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
            String fileaccess = ip+"Mobile/rest.svc/Fileacces?stream="+fis+"&filename="+fname;
            Log.d("Fileaccess","fileaccess"+fileaccess);
            String result = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(fileaccess, ServiceHandler.GET);
            Log.i("fileaccess", "result: > " + result);
            return  null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            System.out.println(s);

        }

    }
```

**My rest function in vb.net**

```
 Public Function fileacces(ByVal stream As FileStream, ByVal filename As String) As String Implements IREST.fileacces
        Dim result = ""

        Try

            Dim path = "D:\XXX\YYY\ECM Source\Archive\EZECM\Settings\Monitor\" + filename
            Dim fileStream = New FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
            stream.CopyTo(fileStream)
            fileStream.Dispose()
            result = "file uploaded"


        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        Return result
    End Function
```

Comment: You need to upload the file and just receive the uploaded data on Rest API, and if this data is too long you may have to upload by parts,

Comment: What is the data type stored on this file path, Is it image, archived or text data.

Comment: All mime type it supports .I select file from my mobile which may be media/* or text/* or application/* and I will click save button in my action bar which should take my file from android to rest where I will store my file in specific path of any drivers.

Answer (score 0):

> kindly use base 64

like this

```
public void uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath) {
    try {


        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFilePath);
        byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

        final String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              //  tvFileName.setText(encoded);
                Log.e("File Base 64",encoded);
                filebas64=encoded;
            }
        });


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Error",e.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Error",e.toString());

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry I am not getting.Please tell me where to use the above function and explain me how it will work?

Comment: try {
                is = new FileInputStream(source);
                int i=0;
                while((i=is.read())!=-1){
                    System.out.print((char)i);
                }
               is.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                                                                                                                              ip+"Mobile/rest.svc/Fileacces?stream="+is+"&filename="+fname;  how to send file stream from android and get it in my rest function?